# "Forbidden. Need User" seems frequently while posting

Tags: ios, quickblox

I have been logged in using Quickblox server with QBRequest.logInWithUserLogin method, after successive login I can fetch user infos from current session
for eg: (QBSession.currentSession().currentUser?.fullName)! as String

When I tried to post QBCOCustomObject with parameters; sometimes it works and sometimes it shows "Forbidden. Need User"

How does it works sometime and don't works rest of time.

Code:

```
        if QBSession.currentSession().currentUser != nil {
            QBRequest.createObject(params, successBlock: { (response, object) in
                MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
                print("create object:", object)
                print("create response:", response.data)

                // Get ID of recent post and create brandTag with multiple brands

                if let data: NSData = response.data{
                    let postId: String = data.valueForKey("_id")! as! String
                    print("Data: \(postId)")
                    let param: QBCOCustomObject = QBCOCustomObject()
                    for brand in self.saveBrand {
                        param.className = "BrandTag"
                        param.fields!["Post_id"] = postId
                        param.fields!["Brand_id"] = BrandQuery.getInstance().retrieveBrandId(brand)

                        QBRequest.createObject(param, successBlock: { (response: QBResponse, object: QBCOCustomObject?) in
                            print("Created BrandTag:", object)
                            }, errorBlock: { (response: QBResponse) in
                                print(response.error!.description)
                        })
                    }
                }else{
                    print("RESPONSE: \(response.data)")
                }


                self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                }, errorBlock: {(response: QBResponse) in
                    MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
                    let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Error Uploading", message: response.error?.description, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel")
                    alert.show()
                    print("Response Error: ", response.error?.description)
            })
        } else {
            MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
            let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Error Uploading", message: "No current user exist", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel")
            alert.show()
            print("No Current User")
        }
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyoOx.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because of one of this case:

1.You are not a logged in user.

2.Session you created is expired.